# How does Ruby ensure only one instance of each number?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have this simple code:

```
a = 1
b = 1
```

Does ruby ensure only one instance of numbers by tracking the numbers (so `a` and `b` would refer to the same object in memory) or just preventing users from creating numbers through the method `new` and duplicating/cloning them?

Comment: Yes, ruby does ensure that `a` and `b` will refer the same object.

Comment: So there could be a sort of 'number table' internally?

Comment: No, that'd be a waste of space for no gain whatsoever. Read this: http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2009/04/21/object-ids-and-fixnums/

Comment: ^ Good reading material

Comment: Whether Ruby returns the same object or a new one is an implementation detail. Don't take it for granted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = 1
b = 1
```

Both `a` and `b` refer to the same object.

```
p a.object_id 
 => 3

p b.object_id
 => 3
```

So when you're comparing `a` and `b` Ruby compares the object ids (as it does with symbols) which makes comparison performant.

The object_id's of integers, interestingly enough, are always odd.  Everything else has even object ids.

Note the comment from Holger Just below which goes into some detail regarding large integers.

Comment: I get `1234567890.object_id` => `44076300`.

Comment: And when I repeat it, I get a different number (also even).

Comment: @StefanPochmann Large integers will eventually be represented by real Ruby objects and can not be stored only as an odd object_id. Depending on the current architecture Ruby is able to store numbers encoded in the object_id itself in the range of `(-2**30 - 1)..(2**30 - 1)` (for 32-bit architectures) or in the range of `(-2**62 - 1)..(2**62 - 1)` (for 64-bit architectures). Other numbers are stored as real Ruby objects with a different object ID in each process. These objects however are held in a lookup table and will thus always have the same object_id in a process (similar to Symbols).

Comment: @HolgerJust Thanks for that explanation. But that lookup table seems to fail then. When I said I get a different number when I repeat `1234567890.object_id`, I meant in the same irb session in consecutive lines. I also tried in a script file and executing that. I even tried `[1234567890, 1234567890].map(&:object_id)` both in irb and in a script file. The object_ids always differ.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I just tried the mapping example you gave and got the same object id twice... 2469135781.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn So you have 64-bit Ruby, I guess? Try with a large enough number then.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Turns out, I was partially wrong. Large numbers are indeed not held in a table, resulting in the same (large) numeric value possibly being represented by different objects with different object_ids. This however is still be safe from a language specification view since the internalizing of Fixnums is an implementation detail that is not strictly required to hold up on other Ruby implementations.

Comment: Just confirmed that `(2**62).object_id` is an even number and doesn't repeat, `(2**62-1).ojbect_id` is an odd number and consistent.  So that's that.